# Run gmt format download from GSEA

Tags: gsea, errors

I built the matrix as the gmt example in https://docs.gsea-msigdb.org/#GSEA/Data_Formats/ but It still has errors when I try to run it.
When I try the gene set from https://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/HALLMARK_ADIPOGENESIS.html
in .gmt format and load it with GSEA appears this error:

Thank you so much

Nerea

```
---- Full Error Message ----
col:34 > matrix's fColCnt:34

---- Stack Trace ----
# of exceptions: 1
------col:34 > matrix's fColCnt:34------
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: col:34 > matrix's fColCnt:34
at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.math.Matrix.getColumnV(Matrix.java:261)
at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.objects.DefaultDataset.getColumn(DefaultDataset.java:289)
at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.objects.TemplateFactory.extract(TemplateFactory.java:85)
at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.alg.DatasetGenerators.extract(DatasetGenerators.java:292)
at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.alg.DatasetGenerators.extract(DatasetGenerators.java:288)
at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/xtools.gsea.AbstractGsea2Tool.execute_one(AbstractGsea2Tool.java:79)
at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/xtools.gsea.AbstractGsea2Tool.execute_one_with_reporting(AbstractGsea2Tool.java:103)
at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/xtools.gsea.Gsea.execute(Gsea.java:166)
at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.xbench.tui.TaskManager$ToolRunnable.run(TaskManager.java:391)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show the first few lines of your input file; from the error, this looks like it might be a formatting issue, and without more information about the format of your file we can't help out.

Comment: Hello It was a formatting issue. Sorry, I solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: Great! glad it's resolved. Could you kindly add your resolution as an answer please? Firstly it helps the site because unresolved question continue to circulate, secondly it helps your reputation on the site. This is useful should you wish to ask another question here in the future.